# google firebase is giving me secret manger error and I can't use "firebase init"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to host my web on fire base and following the tutorial I'm getting a secret manger error that looks like this

```
Error: could not assert Secret Manager permissions. Make sure that Secret Manager is enabled in your GCP project and that the Cloud Build P4SA (service-570924573232@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com) has permissions secretmanager.secrets.create and secretmanager.secrets.setIamPolicy. Error: generic::permission_denied: Permission 'secretmanager.secrets.create' denied for resource 'projects/edrak-fc40c' (or it may not exist).
```

I tried following the google tutorial but I get this error every time and I gave the secret manger accessor role to my project in IAM so I don't know where I'm going wrong

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error. Did you find a solution?